# Return the most recently created custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm using a plugin (IssueM) which gives the "articles" post-type a custom taxonomy called "Issues".

I need to find and store in a variable the most recently created one of this taxonomy. So, for example, within `Issues` I have `issue-one` through to `issue-five` - I need to return `issue-five` as it was created most recently.

How can I access this custom taxonomy by date?

Comment: WordPress doesn't store creation or modification dates for taxonomy terms, so @dougvdotcom's answer below (sorting by the auto-incremented ID#) is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to select that custom taxonomy, ordering by id DESC and returning only one record:

```
$latest_term = get_terms( 'issuem_issues', array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'DESC', 'number' => 1, 'hide_empty' => false );
```

This presumes that your WP DB is set up normally, so the highest ID number on the custom taxonomy terms will be the most recently added term.

Also, make sure the *slug* for the custom taxonomy is Issues, not issues. The slug query is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for this. Problem is when I do this, I get "invalid taxonomy" returned. I have tried both "Issue" and "Issues" just in case.

Comment: The correct taxonomy, I believe, will be issuem_issue if my examination of the plugin's code is correct.

Comment: You are correct. Changed to issuem_issue and gets the most recent. Although it will only get the most recent that has posts applied to it. So even though issue-five exists, it returns issue-four as issue-five has no live articles.

Comment: You can fix this by setting 'hide_empty' to false. Code corrected above.